# How to build for staging with cache busting

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I have a `.env.staging` file with some configs for when I'm building my Vue app for staging.

But if I build now with `vue-cli-service build --mode staging` it will not append a hash to the output files, thus there is no cache busting. (Which is does when there is no "mode")

Is there a way of using the env-file, and still have cache busting?

Comment: Curiously, why use `staging` as a mode when it's purpose (historically) is to represent production in a 1:1 as to ensure there are no issues before going live?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy In the .env file are the API URLs to the staging backend

Comment: Given that you're probably deploying this somewhere, why not just copy that file to `.env.production` during the process instead of relying on `.env.staging` on your server?

Answer (score 1):

The way I accomplished this was to specify the following in the .env.staging file:

```
NODE_ENV=production
```

And then in vue.config.js

```
let config = {};

if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development'){
     config.filenameHashing = true;
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: This worked for me - all I needed to do was add NODE_ENV=production to the .env.staging file though. I didn't need to change the vue.config.js file.